# Changeable navbar content on hover(not on navbar)

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, hover, navbar

I want to create a navbar content change on hover some other element. I have sticky navbar on scroll down and the top of it there is some topics like blog, professional something like that and i want categorize them on navbar. But i need to change them on hover every topic of top at website. And also they need to be stable on every page on topic For example on professional page navbar must fill with professionals sub titles.

```
<div id="NavUst">
<a href="#" id="Link1">
    <div id="elementLogo">
        <img id="logo" src="~/WebSiteİcerik/logo.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#" id="Link2"><div id="elementNu" class="mrgnAyar"><h4>Blog</h4></div></a>
<a href="#" id="Link3"><div id="elementNu" class="mrgnAyar"><h4>Soru-Cevap</h4></div></a>
<a href="#" id="Link4"><div id="elementNu" class="mrgnAyar"><h4>Profesyonel</h4></div></a>
<div id="elementNu">
    <a href="#"> <div id="Login"><h4>Giriş Yap</h4></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="Login"><h5>Kayıt Ol</h5></div></a>
</div>
```

This is my topic div on every  tags hover navbar need to change

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark nav" id="navbar1">
<div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarresponsive" aria-controls="navbarresponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarresponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="NavUstId">
            @if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Sayfa"]) == 1)
            {
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Anasayfa
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servislerimiz</a>
                </li> 
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">İletişim</a>
                </li>
            }
```

and this is part of navbar 
Do i need to show it like modal or something like that ?
I am working on asp.net mvc